# iOS Swift Constrain Line between views, Constrain small shape over other view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

iOS Swift Constrain Line between views
Constrain small shape over other view

I am trying to create a view like the following.  Where images will be inside the circles and a line will connect the two images. I’m stuck on how to constrain that redline between the views

I’m currently using a Stack View for the two bottom circles and a larger one for the three.
[image: linebetween circles]

My second question is how to constrain an element like the following.  First the red circle over the larger circle and then the small box over the larger one.  My thought is to utilise a trailing and bottom constraint and make them both negative
[image: square circle]

Comment: The line might be easier in code. Just draw it from circle1's center to circle2's center. Assuming the line is behind the circles.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for part 1 was to put the 3 balls in a stack view like you suggest and then to have a third view (the line) independent of the stack.

You need to ensure that the line is placed under the stack so it shows through. Then constrain the line with

```
blueLine.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
blueLine.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(greyCircle.centerXAnchor).active = true
blueLine.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(greyCircle.centerYAnchor).active = true
blueLine.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(smallCircle.centerXAnchor).active = true
blueLine.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(smallCircle.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

You can do this either in code or in the storyboard.

Now you have a View with its top left corner in the center of the big circle and bottom right corner in the center of the bottom circle.

But we really want a line and not just a square view. You might make a custom subclass of UIView that just draws a line between the two opposing corners by overriding `drawRect`

```
class LineView : UIView {
  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y) //move to top corner
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 5)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, rect.origin.x + rect.size.width, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
  }
}
```

For the other case you should be able to just constrain trailing edges and bottom edges to be equal.